# BookMark Redirection using AOP-Spring interceptor

Tags: spring-mvc, aop, interceptor

I was trying to write an interceptor using spring AOP.The interceptor will find if a request URL is a bookmark,if so will redirect to the authentication page.
Code Snippet:

public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        logger.entering(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "invoke", invocation);

```
    Object result = null;
    try {
        // Logic to exclude the beans as per the list in the configuration.
        boolean excluded = false;
        for (String excludebean : excludedBeans) {
            if (excludebean != null && excludebean.equalsIgnoreCase(invocation.getThis().getClass().getSimpleName())) {
                excluded = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If the Target Method is "toString", then set EXCLUDE to TRUE and process the request
        if(excluded == false && invocation.getMethod().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("toString"))
        {
            excluded = true;
        }

        // if user session object is available, then process the request or
        // else forward to the configured view.
        if (excluded || getSessionHolder().getUserVO() != null) {
            result = invocation.proceed();
        }
        else {
            logger.logp(Level.INFO, this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    "invoke(MethodInvocation)", "User Object is "+ getSessionHolder().getUserVO()
                            + ". So redirecting user to home page");
            result = new ModelAndView("redirect:/security/authenticate.do");

        }
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    logger.exiting(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "invoke");
    return result;
}
```

When I debug the control comes inside the else block as expected but after I return the result,control goes to the handle method for the bookmarked URl ratehr than the handler for the redirect view.

Pls help me on this..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why Do you need AOP for the interceptor. You can redirect easily using Regular interceptor.

```
public class RedirectInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

    private String redirectMapping;

    public void setRedirectMapping(String redirectMapping) {
        this.redirectMapping = **maintenanceMapping**;
    }


    //before the actual handler will be executed
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
                        if (somethingHappened){
            response.sendRedirect(redirectMapping);
            return false;
                        } else
                          return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this way,i have a debug point inside my interceptor but the control never comes inside,i have added my interceptor to <mvc:interceptors>..Am using annotation based url mapping.pls help.

Comment: hi denny,i got t wrong with the mapping path..It works now,Thanks a lot